# Adding metadata to millions of S3 objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I have an S3 bucket with over 20 million objects (2.3TB).

The objects need to have their content-disposition metadata populated with user defined names while preserving their existing content-type metadata.

The file names are stored in a separate RDS database.

It looks like I would be able to use the copy command for a small number of files but with a bucket this big it doesn't really sound like a sane option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its seems a perfect use case for [S3 Batch operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops.html). So you could create a lambda function which would conduct your changes concurrently through the S3 Batch.